# When I try to rename a file in VS2010 with TFS, it just changes back to the original name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm trying to rename a JS file in my project. I have tried right clicking on the file and then clicking 'rename', typing in the new file name and then pressing 'enter'. However, it just reverts back to the old name.

I am connected to TFS and I tried renaming the file with it checked out by me and also with it not checked out and experienced the same results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is your old name by chance only different by case? If you try to rename "myfile.txt" to "MyFile.txt" you will get the result you report.

Yes, its a silly limitation, however you should be able to do  "myfile.txt"-> "MyFile2.txt" -> "MyFile.txt" and checkin..

Comment: Hi, nope it is not only different by case.